# Is there a constant uniform relationship between arc lengths of a sphere and their corresponding 'descents' of the radius?

Tags: geometry

Regarding a bowling ball, a billiard ball and a ping-pong ball:

These 3 balls, to me, look and feel to have a uniform curvature.
Their curvature characteristics are always the same everywhere on each ball.

The same uniformity of curvature holds true for any represented circle that I have ever seen.

5 questions:

(1)  Is there a relationship between a measured “arc length” of a sphere or a circle and the corresponding “descent” of that sphere or circle’s radius?

(2)  If so, is the relationship constant between two or more “arc lengths” (having varying lengths) and the corresponding radius “descent” of each “arc length” of that specific sphere or circle?

(3)  If so, is this relationship constant regardless of the size of the sphere or circle?

(4) Would it be correct to describe this relationship in the following words:  “the ‘descent’ of the radius divided by the length of an ‘arc’?

(5) Might this relationship be expressed as a constant real number, such as,  0.63661977236 (2/pi) or, perhaps,  0.31830988618 (1/pi)?

In case my 5 questions (above) are badly or incorrectly worded, let me provide 6 real world examples (below) that may more accurately describe the relationship I am trying to discover.

I have in my hands a ten pin bowling ball that has the standard diameter of  8.5".
On one side of the bowling ball, I mark 2 points, A and B.
Using a piece of string, I measure the surface distance between A and B as being 2.63".
I place the bowling ball on to the hard surface of a flat table.
I position the ball so that point A is at the very top of the top of the ball, at “12 o’clock”.
I rotate the ball so that point B is as close to the table as it can be (keeping A at 12 o’clock).

(1)  What is the straight line distance between point B and the table?

On the other side of the bowling ball, I mark 2 points, C and D.
Using a piece of string, I measure the surface distance between C and D as being 3.94".
I position the ball so that point C is at the very top of the top of the ball, at “12 o’clock”.
I rotate the ball so that point D is as close to the table as it can be (keeping C at 12 o’clock).

(2)  What is the straight line distance between point D and the table?

I have in my hands a billiard ball that has the standard diameter of 2.25".
On one side of the billiard ball, I mark 2 points, E and F.
Using a piece of string, I measure the surface distance between E and F as being 1.09" .
I place the billiard ball on to the hard surface of a flat table.
I position the ball so that point E is at the very top of the top of the ball, at “12 o’clock”.
I rotate the ball so that point F is as close to the table as it can be (keeping E at 12 o’clock).

(3)  What is the straight line distance between point F and the table?

On the other side of the billiard ball, I mark 2 points, G and H.
Using a piece of string, I measure the surface distance between G and H as being 0.55".
I position the ball so that point G is at the very top of the top of the ball, at “12 o’clock”.
I rotate the ball so that point H is as close to the table as it can be (keeping G at 12 o’clock).

(4)  What is the straight line distance between point H and the table?

I have in my hands a ping-pong ball that has the standard diameter of 1.57".
On one side of the ping-pong ball, I mark 2 points, J and K.
Using a piece of string, I measure the surface distance between J and K as being 0.39".
I place the ping-pong ball on to the hard surface of a flat table.
I position the ball so that point J is at the very top of the top of the ball, at “12 o’clock”.
I rotate the ball so that point K is as close to the table as it can be (keeping J at 12 o’clock).

(5)  What is the straight line distance between point K and the table?

On the other side of the ping-pong ball, I mark 2 points, L and M.
Using a piece of string, I measure the surface distance between L and M as being 0.62".
I position the ball so that point L is at the very top of the top of the ball, at “12 o’clock”.
I rotate the ball so that point M is as close to the table as it can be (keeping L at 12 o’clock).

(6)  What is the straight line distance between point M and the table?

I am superficially asking for 6 real number answers expressed in inches.

But what I am really asking is:  Does there exist a real number constant that expresses a uniform relationship between the length of an arc and its 'descent' of the radius and might that constant hold true for all sizes of spheres and circles?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: It seems like you did the same measurement on multiple spherical objects, but unfortunately I'm having a hard time visualizing what you did. It would help if you could draw a diagram for your measurements, using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry) perhaps.

Comment: There is a general agreement to call curvature of  a circle or a sphere with radius $R$ the quantity $1/R$. Besides, using a notation like 0.55" (inches as I assume ; I had never met the double quote abbreviation) isn't the best to be understood by scientists ; consider using metric system.

Comment: What do you mean by "the descent of the radius"? I guess it's got something to do with the "straight line distance" in your various ball measurements, but it's not clear what the connection is. A diagram or two would be helpful. Also, with that straight line distance are you asking about the vertical distance to the table (which passes through the ball if the arc length is less than 1/4 of the circumference)? Or are you talking about the tangential distance (which is what you'd measure with a ruler resting on the ball's surface at that point)?

Comment: Your questions can (probably) be easily answered with standard trigonometry, but we need to properly understand your questions before we can answer them. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is a relationship between the arc distance from the "top" of a spherical object and the straight-line distance to the table on which the sphere is placed.
Whether it is "uniform" depends on how you define the relationship.

Take a sphere of radius $r$. Mark two points $P$ and $Q$ on the surface of the sphere. Measure the distance between the points along the shortest path that follows the surface of the sphere (the path the string will take when pulled tight); suppose this distance is $s$.

Put the sphere on top of a flat horizontal plane with $P$ at the very "top" of the sphere; this means that the sphere contacts the plane at a point $P'$ exactly opposite from $P$, that is, the line segment $PP'$ passes through the sphere's center and is a diameter of the sphere.

Note that if you keep the sphere in contact with the plane with $P$ positioned at the "top", you must keep $P'$ in contact with the horizontal plane, and the only way to rotate the sphere under these constraints is to rotate it around the axis $PP'.$
As you do so, the point $Q$ traces a horizontal circle over the horizontal plane, that is, it is always at the same distance from the plane, that is, it is always as close as it can be to the plane.

Now if $O$ is the point at the exact center of the sphere, the angle
$\angle POQ$ is $s/r$ radians.
Let $\theta = s/r.$
If we then take a cross-section of this entire construction in the vertical plane through $P,$ $Q$, $P'$, and $O$, it starts to look like this:

[image]

To complete the figure, we drop a perpendicular line from $Q$ to the horizontal plane below, intersecting the plane at $Q'$,
and we put $N$ on the diameter $PP'$ so that $NQ$ is perpendicular to $PP'.$
Let the distance $NO$ be $v$ and let the distance $QQ'$ be $h$;
the distance $h$ is the straight-line distance between $Q$ and the horizontal plane (aka table), which is what you asked about.

A little trigonometry tells us that
$$v = r \cos(\theta) = r \cos\left(\frac sr\right).$$
Also, we can observe that $P'NQQ'$ is a rectangle and that
$NP' = NO + OP' = v + r = h = QQ'.$
So the formula for $h$ is
$$ h = r + v = r + r \cos\left(\frac sr\right). \tag1 $$

Take any of your examples, replace $r$ with the ball's radius and replace $s$ with the length of the string, and then $h$ computed by the formula above will be the straight-line distance from the lower end of the string to the table.

There is not going to be a uniform formula that gets you directly from $s$ to $h$. The formula also must involve $r.$
That is, if you are simply measuring the arc length and "descent" in inches,
every spherical object with a different radius is going to have a different "descent" for a given arc length.

Even if you consider just one radius, there is no constant you can multiply by the string length to find the "descent".
The amount by which the function value $\cos(s/r)$ changes is not proportional to the amount by which $s$ changes.

You can simplify things a little bit if you measure everything relative to the radius of the ball rather than just using the number of inches.
Measured relative to the radius of the ball, the length of the string is
$\theta = s/r$ (that's what we mean when we say the angle is $\theta$ *radians*).
Let $\delta$ be the distance from $Q$ to the horizontal plane below,
measured relative to the radius of the ball;
then $\delta = h/r.$
Dividing both sides of Equation $(1)$ above by $r$ we find that

$$ \frac hr = 1 + \cos\left(\frac sr\right), $$

that is,

$$ \delta = 1 + \cos(\theta). $$

This is about as simple a relationship as you will be able to find between the arc length from $P$ to $Q$ and the height of $Q$ above the plane.